# Fourier Transform is continuous on Schwartz space

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

For $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we define the seminorm 
$$\|f\|_{\alpha,\beta} : = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} |x^\alpha \partial^\beta \phi(x)|$$
but I don't quite understand the argument below after the author defined the constant $C=...$

**Edit:** with the Leibniz formula, we get $$\partial^\alpha (-ix)^\beta \phi(x) = \sum_{\lambda+\pi = \alpha} \frac{\alpha !}{\lambda ! \pi !} \partial^\lambda (-ix)^\beta \partial^\pi \phi(x)$$ if I want to calculate this, do I have to split it into different cases because of the term $\partial^\lambda (-ix)^\beta$ .

[image]

Comment: He's talking about the Leibniz product rule for multi-indices, not the  for interchanging derivatives and integrals.

Comment: The formula gives me $$\partial^\alpha (-ix)^\beta \phi(x) = \sum_{\lambda+\pi = \alpha} \frac{\alpha !}{\lambda ! \pi !} \partial^\lambda (-ix)^\beta \partial^\pi \phi(x)$$ if I want to calculate this, do I have to split it into different cases because of the term $\partial^\lambda (-ix)^\beta$ .

Comment: which book this is?